# Python2 base64 strict decode still silently ignores invalid characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, base64

For some reason, I can't get the following snippet to error although it should.

Calling python2's base64 decoding function `decodestring` with nonprintable characters, I expect an exception to be raised, however:

```
In [1]: import base64

In [2]: base64.decodestring("\x01\x01\x01")
Out[2]: ''
```

For comparison, using the string class's method yields the same result:

```
In [7]: "\x01\x01\x01".decode("base64")
Out[7]: ''
```

However doing the equivalent for hex will indeed provide the expected behavior (note an additional character was added to align to multiples of two, as expected by the hex decoder):

```
In [9]: "\x01\x01\x01\x01".decode("hex")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-1e73b7069a1d> in <module>()
----> 1 "\x01\x01\x01\x01".decode("hex")

/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/hex_codec.pyc in hex_decode(input, errors)
     40     """
     41     assert errors == 'strict'
---> 42     output = binascii.a2b_hex(input)
     43     return (output, len(input))
     44

TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found
```

Several other attempts proved that the behavior encountered is that the base64 decoder, specifically, **ignores** any invalid characters instead of raising an error. This behavior is experienced although the decoder is documented to only support the default strict error handling mode:

```
In [11]: "\x01\x01\x01".decode("base64", errors="ignore")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e0b65726a302> in <module>()
----> 1 "\x01\x01\x01".decode("base64", errors="ignore")

/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/base64_codec.pyc in base64_decode(input, errors)
     39
     40     """
---> 41     assert errors == 'strict'
     42     output = base64.decodestring(input)
     43     return (output, len(input))

AssertionError:
```

The behavior is also experienced regardless of the method used to execute the builtin base64 codec that is bundled with python2.7.

Additionally, any valid character will be processed properly, yielding weird results such as the following:

```
In [6]: base64.decodestring("\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01AA==")
Out[6]: '\x00'

In [7]: base64.decodestring("\x01A\x01A\x01=\x01=\x01A")
Out[7]: '\x00'

In [8]: base64.decodestring("\x01Not\x01A\x01Base64\x01String\x01")
Out[8]: '6\x8b@\x05\xab\x1e\xeb\x84\xad\xae)\xe0'
```

My question is two-fold:

1. Am I correct in my analysis of this behavior?
2. Why was this the behavior implemented instead of conforming with other codecs and the `errors="strict"` API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base64 was invented to allow binary file encapsulation into text only protocols. Those protocols could have other limitations, like the maximum size of a line, which required to insert end of lines in the base64 encoded strings. In order to be as tolerant as possible on input, many decoders decided to just ignore any non printing character.

That is the way the Python base64 module was designed.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! Wouldn't it make sense to support the base64 errors="ignore" instead?